# Is polygamy strictly forbidden for women in Islam?

Tags: women, polygamy

Is there an ayet in Koran that prevents a woman from marrying more than one man ? If not, what's the general consensus on the topic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's neither a clear Verse nor a Verse one could conclude from that a woman could marry more than one man. But we have a clear and long Hadith in [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/63) and [Sunan abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/98) explaining the different forms of marriage which existed in Jahilya and how Islam prohibited all but one of them!

Therefore there is no doubt among Muslim scholars that this is prohibited, as it seems to go against on of the major the goals of the Islamic shari'a  مقاصد الشريعة, which is to secure and guard the offspring!

Please: read also this [Article](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-logic-behind-a-male-can-have-4-wives-at-a-time-where-in-a-female-can-at-a-time-have-only-one-husband-Can-someone-tell-me-how-Quran-justifies-this) and [here](http://www.14publications.com/question-and-answer/why-cant-a-woman-have-2-husbands/) where many issues have been explained about the matter of polyandry (a woman having more then one husband)! Also [here](http://www.islamiccentre.org/ask-an-alim-mainmenu-88/23-marriage-faqs/445-why-cant-women-have-multiple-husbands-) some logical reasons why polyandry creates social, ethical and personal problems.

Here's a short overview on some of these issues:

1. The identity of the child becomes ambiguous. -> Inheritance problems etc.
2. Growth Stunts.-> A woman can only birth for one healthy child "each year", how could she satisfy the wishes of more then one husband if each wants a certain number of children?
3. The stronger and mightier husbands will sleep with the wife when they want to...
4. If a husband becomes bed-bound due to an accident for a few months, then he will need his wife to look after him day and night.
5. Economics: the husband should care about the family, but which husband and if he doesn't have children yet with the wife ...
6. Women find they cannot sometimes fulfill the sexual desires of their husband, due to monthly periods, pregnancies and so on.
   ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see the logical reasoning behind it. However, you say that "there's neither a clear Verse nor a Verse one could conclude from that a woman could marry more than one man." What about the opposite ? Is there a verse that strictly forbids it for women ? Or logical deductions from hadiths is all we have ?

Comment: Well there's only a Verse in the Qur'an which allows polygamy (one husband and multiple wife's) under what one could describe as hard conditions. And this Hadith tell's what the Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) thought people and applied in the society he was "leading". As Muslims are required to follow his example the logical deduction comes from this! And from the understanding of the shria'a as a whole thing -> purposes or goals of shari'a!